# How to give menu in common function

Tags: javascript, optimization, extjs

I have a two `splitbuttons` with different ids. Split buttons have some menu. In my case both the split buttons having the same menu. My question how can I optimize the code and write the menu in some common function.

Here is my code example.

```
{
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: "Button1",
    hidden: true,
    id : 'Button1',
    menu:[{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        }],
    handler:function(){
        this.SomeFunction();
    }
},{
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: "Button2",
    hidden: true,
    id : 'Button2',
    menu:[{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        },{
            text: "A1",
        }],
    handler:function(){
        this.SomeFunction();
    }
}
```

Here you can see both `Button1` and `Button2` having same menu. How can I optimize my code and make menu in some common place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `buildMenuItems` method in the class, that returns the menu items:

```
buildMenuItems: function() {
    return [{
        text: "A1",
    },{
        text: "A1",
    },{
        text: "A1",
    },{
        text: "A1",
    }];
}
```

And then replace the common menu items definition with a call to this function.

```
{
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: "Button1",
    hidden: true,
    id: 'Button1',
    menu: this.buildMenuItems(),
    handler: function () {
        this.SomeFunction();
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'splitbutton',
    text: "Button2",
    hidden: true,
    id: 'Button2',
    menu: this.buildMenuItems(),
    handler: function () {
        this.SomeFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class for each split button that has property of xtype, text, hidden, id, menu, handler.

now add a method for menu management, add, delete, update. so you can do it like:

```
var btnObj = new ButtonSplit(xtype, 'text', isHidden);
btnObj.addMenu("A1");
```

creating a class is useful, so in the future you may be able to modify your class and add method such as btnClass.addManyMenus(["A1", "A2", "A3"]);